# How do I edit a variable inside of a defined code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The program wont add +1 to "total".
Is there a better way to program this?
I also mainly use Pycharm which that could possibly .

```
from tkinter import * #imports tkinter

window = Tk() #Tk name

window.title("Cookie Clicker")#window title

window.geometry('350x200')#window size

lbl = Label(window, text="$0.00")#makes label

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)#makes label

x=0  #possibly a problem
total=0 #possibly a problem

def clicked():  
    total = total+1  # also possibly causing problems
    lbl.configure(text='${:,.2f}'.format(total))#This is possibly causing problems 

btn = Button(window, text="Cookie", command=clicked)#This is the button

btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `total` isn't defined in the function. You can fix this by making `total` a global variable:

```
def clicked():
    global total  
    total = total+1
    lbl.configure(text='${:,.2f}'.format(total))
```

This makes `total` a global variable, meaning the function can change it's value in the global namespace. You need to use `global` in every function that you want to be able to access the variable.

Another solution would be using an object-orientated approach and making `total` an attribute.

Comment: *meaning it's value can be changed by all functions.*... Not exactly. It means that the function you defined global in can then check the global namespace for the variable name. Not all function can then edit it. Because each function needs to have global defined within it.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, thanks for your clarification. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dude Ur A GOD

Answer (score 0):

In the future please include the error you get from your code. Your example code would tell you exactly what is wrong with the traceback error it produces.

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\user\neon\workspace\OLD_MINT\OM\Test3.py", line 17, in
>   clicked
>       total = total+1  # also possibly causing problems UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

The key information in this traceback is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

This tells you the Function views `total` as a local variable and is complaining that you are trying to reference before it has been assigned. This part specifically `total+1`.

To correct something like this you will need to tell your function that `total` is a global variable so the function will look in the global namespace first.

Now you might wonder if this is the case then why is the label (`lbl`) able to be updated without defining global. This is because python has a way of guess if something is local or a global variable.

If you try to edit something and not actually assign it then python will first look locally in the function and then if it does not find it it will look in the global namespace. I am not sure on all the details but this is generally what it is doing.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Cookie Clicker")
window.geometry('350x200')
lbl = Label(window, text="$0.00")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

x=0
total=0

def clicked():
    global total # tell the function total is in the global namespace. 
    total = total+1
    lbl.configure(text='${:,.2f}'.format(total))

btn = Button(window, text="Cookie", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
mainloop()
```